# How often does a PHP session ID change per user?

Tags: php, session

Just a basic question, if you open a session when a user visits the main page and you store the session id. When would that user return say another day/time and the id be different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depends on how the PHP is configured. specifically these settings control how often a php session id is "erased" by garbage collector:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which
>   data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage
>   collection may occur during session start (depending on
>   session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor

> session.gc_divisor coupled with session.gc_probability defines the
>   probability that the gc (garbage collection) process is started on
>   every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using
>   gc_probability/gc_divisor, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that
>   the GC process starts on each request. session.gc_divisor defaults to
>   100.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability

> session.gc_probability in conjunction with session.gc_divisor is used
>   to manage probability that the gc (garbage collection) routine is
>   started. Defaults to 1. See session.gc_divisor for details.

As far as i know the default php `session.gc_maxlifetime` is 1440 seconds (24 minutes). The more visits you have in your site the most "accurate" these statistics are since all this algorithm will run more often.

A tricky *edge* case: if you start a session and then NEVER get any other visit to your site, the garbage collector algorithm will never run, hence the session will never expire! If you can understand this, i think you have understood this answer.